# How to filter observations before and at a maximum value in a variable with optimum response in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a response variable measured across days that have sort of an optimal response. Here I have a mock data set.

```
data.a <- read.csv(text = "
year,location,treatment,day,response
2015,loc_a,High,1,10
2015,loc_a,High,2,20
2015,loc_a,High,3,30
2015,loc_a,High,4,20
2015,loc_a,High,5,10
2015,loc_a,High,6,3
2015,loc_a,Medium,1,1
2015,loc_a,Medium,2,2
2015,loc_a,Medium,3,3
2015,loc_a,Medium,4,4
2015,loc_a,Medium,5,5
2015,loc_a,Medium,6,4
2015,loc_a,Low,1,100
2015,loc_a,Low,2,200
2015,loc_a,Low,3,300
2015,loc_a,Low,4,400
2015,loc_a,Low,5,500
2015,loc_a,Low,6,600
")
```

Basically, I need to filter the days which response correspond to response before and at the optimum. This is what I tried but is not working.

```
data.b <- data.a %>% group_by(year,location,treatment) 
                        %>% filter(response <= which.max(response))
```

I know the code is wrong because all the response values are at or below the maximum. However, I could't find a way around. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code filters to all values where the response is <= the maximum response value (as you mention). What you really want is to filter the indices, rather than the values, for being <= the maximum.

You can do this with `slice`:

```r
data.a %>%
  group_by(year, location, treatment) %>%
  slice(1:which.max(response))
```